# Form works without check but stops won't insert with check

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to preform a quick check on the email entered by a user and provide user with an error if the email field is not unique.  I have setup the database to keep this field unique now its about telling the user what they did wrong.

If I run the script below without the email check I can insert values into the table fine.  All messages work and the table updates if it is a new email.

But when I add the email check code it will recognize a bad entry and provide the error but it will not proceed to enter the values if the email is good.

```
<?php

require('connect.php');

// If the values are posted, insert them into the database.

if (isset($_POST['rname']) && isset($_POST['email'])){

    $rname = $_POST['rname'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

    $emailcheck = "select email from entries where email = ".$email."";
    if (mysql_num_rows != 1) 
    {
     $err = "Error email already registered!";
    } else {


    $query = "INSERT INTO `entries` (rname, fname, email) VALUES ('$rname', '$fname', '$email')";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result){

        $msg = "Thanks, you have successfully registered.";

    }

}

}

?>
```

Trouble code is this section here

```
    $emailcheck = "select email from entries where email = ".$email."";
    if (mysql_num_rows != 1) 
    {
     $err = "Error email already registered!";
    } else {
```

Comment: you didn't even execute that query, thats just a string, where did you get this code? you copied this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose the strings in a query within quotes and have to execute it using mysql_query(). Both are missing in your code.

```
 $emailcheck = mysql_query("select email from entries where email = '$email'");
```

Also the syntax for `mysql_num_rows()` is wrong in your code. It should be :

```
int mysql_num_rows ( resource $result )
```

ie,.

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($emailcheck ) >0 )    // if email already exists
 {
     $err = "Error email already registered!";
 }
```

Comment: Changes errors out on the mysql_num_rows line with both good & bad values.

"Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"

With the old line there I get nothing, no errors, no data entry.

Comment: $emailcheck = mysql_query("select email from entries where email = ".$email."");
         if (mysql_num_rows($emailcheck ) >0 ) 
        {
         $err = "Error email already registered!";
        } else {

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `entries` (rname, fname, email) VALUES ('$rname', '$fname', '$email')");

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if($result){

            $msg = "Thanks, you have successfully registered.";

        }

Comment: Please make your query proper. Still you have problems with the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

and please remember this is only temparary form. and ugly one too. so dont worry about it use your original form.

```
<?php

require('connect.php');

// If the values are posted, insert them into the database.

if (isset($_POST['rname']) && isset($_POST['email'])){

    $rname = $_POST['rname'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

    $emailcheck = mysql_query("select email from entries where email = '$email'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($emailcheck) >0) 
    {
     $err = "Error email already registered!";
     echo $err;
    } else {




    $query = "INSERT INTO `entries` (rname, fname, email) VALUES ('$rname', '$fname', '$email')";

    $result = mysql_query($query);


    if($result){

        $msg = "Thanks, you have successfully registered.";
        echo $msg;

    }

}

}

?>
//the form is here just for reference. as you can see all the type are text. i just made it to check
//weather it going to work or not
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="rname"><br>
<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
<input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload file">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It generated the same "Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource" error. Thank you for your try.

While I still don't understand why my fix worked when the code I posted here did not but I found a solution.  By moving the check for duplicate emails to an else statement after the insert I am able to run that check and produce an error message for users.  Since the database is configured to reject duplicate entries this option will work.  I can now focu my efforts on escaping all entries and trying to ensure the script is hardened against hacking attempts.

Thanks for your efforts.